# Javascript how to assign a data field to a variable

Tags: javascript, html

I have this code in my HTML code. I'm trying to assign a field to a variable and then show it in my HTML code. What I'm trying to accomplish is showing in my HTML code just the last four digits of the 'ID' data field, right now shows 8 digits. This is my code:

```
<body onload="myFunction()">

<script>
  function myFunction() 
  {
    var str = ID //'ID' IS A DATA FIELD BUT 'STR' VARIABLE DOESN'T TAKE IT**
    var res = str.substring(5, 8);
    document.getElementById("javi").innerHTML = res;
  }
</script>
```

And then I call it int the html body

```
<p id="javi"></p>
```

Comment: What is the content of `ID`? Where did it came from? You forgot `;` in assigning another values to variable `str`. Your `<script>` should also be `<script type="text/javascript">`.

Comment: You might say a data field is in an input in a form element. In your tag `<p id="java">`, id is an attribute. Attributes that begin with `data-` such as `data-name="javi"` are data attributes. I think @curiousgeorge answered your question appropriately although the title of your post may be misleading.

Comment: ID is a reference to a data field. I'm using a program where I load two things. One is a .dbf file and Second is a .HTML file. Inside the html I put the name of any column of the .dbf inside <p> to show them. The problem is that when I declare the little JavaScript code to just show the last 4 digits of the ID field, I don't know how to set my condition to get the input from the ID field, right now is taking it as a String, is just printing "ID".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var str = document.getElementById('Javi').textContent
```

should get you the text of your `p`

from there your substring should work

Comment: Please be aware that `textContent` does not work in < IE 9. For < IE 9 support you need assign `innerText` too.